# Javascript querySelectorAll, how to match with only top elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, selectors-api

I am using polymer.

Let say I have something in Template as follows

```
<ul>    
    <li>
        Home
    </li>
    <li>
        About
    </li>
    <li>
        Actions
        <ul>
            <li>
                Logout
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

In Ready function

```
var listNodes = this.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
```

I need help with this javascript query selector. The current query I applied gives me **li** of all **ul** from that template. But I want **li** of top **ul** only. I don't want all children **li** of template.
I think changing it to proper query, I might get the right result. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: What your expected output from given code?

Comment: Output will be node of 3 three li's.

Comment: @Mohit thanks susing [].filter.call(tabs.querySelectorAll(":scope > my-tab") I am able to get details having some other issue with parent selectors. Thank you

Comment: `document.querySelector("ul").children` ...By using `querySelector()`, you're only selecting the first `ul` on the page. Then `.children` gives you the `li` elements directly below it.

Comment: Hang on, why did you tag the question with jquery?

Comment: so that those who use jquery can also answer the question. It's about selector.

Comment: @VivekMuthal That's a bad use of `filter`, you should be using `forEach` since you are not actually filtering anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Mohit's comment. Able to figure out the answer.

```
var listNodes = this.querySelectorAll('ul:scope > li');
```

Comment: I don't see Mohit's comment anywhere, please add some explanation. `:scope` is not very well supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wLpCy/3/ this can be used to support many browsers to `:scope`

Comment: @JuanMendes Mohit has deleted the comment. It was having one demo link ie.http://jsfiddle.net/wLpCy/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have to know something about the li. If it's at the top level of the document, use `body > ul > li`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li'))
```

```html
<ul>    
    <li>
        Home
    </li>
    <li>
        About
    </li>
    <li>
        Actions
        <ul>
            <li>
                Logout
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Otherwise, you must have a way to uniquely identify the parent of the ul

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#user-content > ul > li'))
```

```html
<div id="user-content">
<ul>    
    <li>
        Home
    </li>
    <li>
        About
    </li>
    <li>
        Actions
        <ul>
            <li>
                Logout
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A manual solution isn't all that bad, just find the first list and then iterate over its child elements:

```
var topList = document.querySelector('ul');

[].forEach.call(topList.children, function(el) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/kidoyatova/1/)

If the list has an identifiable parent element (such as body or an element with id), you can use the immediate descendant operator (`>`).

#### Update

Since your question is tagged with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), here's another solution:

```
$('ul:first > li').each(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying an id or some unique selector to the top element like this:

```
<ul id="top">    
    <li>
        Home
    </li>
    <li>
        About
    </li>
    <li>
        Actions
        <ul>
            <li>
                Logout
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Would allow you to get the top elements like this:

```
var topElems = document.querySelectorAll("#top > li");
```

You could do other unique selectors like `body > ul > li` but the idea is you have to uniquely identify your top `ul` element to search from.

**Edit**

If it's inside a polymer template you could do something like `template > ul > li`.

Comment: no I can't add Id's using polymer the template will be given by user.

Comment: sorry it doesn't help.

Comment: Does changing `template` to `content` fix anything? Could you post your polymer element or at least some of it's `html` so I can help diagnose this specific case?

Comment: Is `<ul>` guaranteed to be the first element in the light DOM?

Comment: thanks but it is solved using the :scope in the query selector.

Answer (score 0):

`ul > li` checks for all `ul` elements having `li` as direct children. That's why you are getting all `ul` and `li`.

If you want to limit to the top level `ul` , `li` element alone. Then use the immediate `parent` of ul tag for this.

```
   document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li')
```

Assuming `body` to be the immediate parent of `ul`. In case you have a wrapper div / any other element with class or ID use that as well in place of body.